# Calling a variable from a plugin file's function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

This is WordPress-related but is a general question.

The plugin I use has a function with a variable I want to use in a template, but I can't figure out how to call the variable. On its own, with an echo command, nothing shows. The function class (if needed) is class_wpp_property_import and the variable I need is  $import_time  This is the actual function:

```
  static public function wpp_publish_box_options( $id ) {
global $post, $wp_properties;

if( !$wpp_import_schedule_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpp_import_schedule_id', true ) ) {
  return;
}

//** Get time stamp from new format ( Version 2.6.0+ ) */
$import_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpp_import_time', true );

//** Get time stamp from old meta_key ( pre-version 2.6.0 ) if new meta_key does not exist */
if( empty( $import_time ) ) {
  $import_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpp_xml_import', true );
}

$import_url = admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=property&page=wpp_property_import#{$wpp_import_schedule_id}" );

$import_name = $wp_properties[ 'configuration' ][ 'feature_settings' ][ 'property_import' ][ 'schedules' ][ $wpp_import_schedule_id ][ 'name' ];

$disable_update = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpp::disable_xmli_update', true );
$text = __( 'Ignore updates on XMLI process', ud_get_wpp_importer()->domain );

if( !empty( $import_time ) ) {
  $import_time = date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i', ud_get_wpp_importer()->domain ), strtotime( $import_time ) );
  ?>

  <div class="misc-pub-section-last">
    <?php echo WPP_F::checkbox( "name=wpp::disable_xmli_update&id=wpp_xmli_disable_update&label=$text", $disable_update ); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="misc-pub-section xml_import_time misc-pub-section-last">
    <span class="wpp_i_time_stamp"><?php printf( __( 'Imported on: <b>%1$s</b> <a href="%2$s" title="%3$s">Importer</a>', ud_get_wpp_importer()->domain ), $import_time, $import_url, $import_name ); ?>
      <b></b></span>
  </div>
<?php
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on variable scoping will explain this better than I can, see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more details, but here's the gist:

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.

But, PHP allows you to abuse scope with the `global` keyword.  It's name is misleading, basically it allows you to import a variable defined outside of the current scope into your current scope.  `$import_time` requires a `$post`, which should be available on template pages, so calling `global $post` in our function should allow us to access it.

Calling `global $import_time` wouldn't work as it isn't defined "globally" (literally, above everything else) like `$post` is.

```php
// in functions.php, or wherever you want

function convertImportTime(?string $import_time, string $format = 'M j, Y @ G:i'): ?string
{
    if (!$import_time) {
        return null;
    }

    return date_i18n(
        __($format, ud_get_wpp_importer()->domain),
        strtotime($import_time)
    ); 
}

function getImportTime(): ?string
{
    global $post;

    if (!$post) {
        return null;
    }

    $import_time = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpp_import_time', true);

    if (!$import_time) {
        $import_time = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpp_xml_import', true);
    }

    return convertImportTime($import_time);
}
```

```html
// template.php

<h1><?php echo getImportTime(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! Well - I think I'm getting there! I actually get an output. I get a string of numbers: 1620336825 instead of the date which might have to do with the part of the initial function 'if( !empty( $import_time ) ) {
  $import_time = date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i', ud_get_wpp_importer()->domain ), strtotime( $import_time ) );
  ?>'

Comment: Yes I think that's exactly it.  I'll update to include that.

Comment: I would send you boxes of wine if I could. You're amazing.

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: I just realized that the year is wrong. It's giving a different year for each one. Far off, like 4021, etc.

Comment: Could play around with `return date($format, $import_time);` (or implementing something using `DateTime` https://www.php.net/datetime) in `convertImportTime()`.  Dates are complicated.